# How to unpack multidimensional array into variables in Julia

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, julia, iterable-unpacking

In Python I can do:

```
a = array([[1,2],[3,4]])
row1, row2 = a
```

Is there an equivalent one-liner in Julia? This doesn't seem to work:

```
a = [[1 2]; [3 4]]
row1, row2 = a
```

Instead it sets row1=1 and row2=3. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you are doing you could use a `Vector{Vector{T}}`, like python list of lists instead of a `Matrix` (`Array{T,2}`).

In `v0.5+` it just works, with `[ , ]`:

```rb
julia> VERSION
v"0.5.0-dev+4440"

julia> a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 2]
 [3, 4]

julia> a = [[1, 2]; [3, 4]]
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4

julia> row1, row2 = a;

julia> (row1, row2)
(2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2,2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
 4)
```

In `v0.4+` you need to type the array as an array of arrays, like so:

```rb
julia> VERSION
v"0.4.5"

julia> a = Vector[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
2-element Array{Array{T,1},1}:
 [1,2]
 [3,4]

julia> b = [[1, 2]; [3, 4]]
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4

julia> c = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
WARNING: [a,b] concatenation is deprecated; use [a;b] instead
 in depwarn at deprecated.jl:73
 in oldstyle_vcat_warning at abstractarray.jl:29
 in vect at abstractarray.jl:32
while loading no file, in expression starting on line 0
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4

julia> row1, row2 = a;

julia> row1, row2
([1,2],[3,4])
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Although all the answers thus far have useful insights, your's is the only one that actually lets me do `row1, row2 = a`, so I'm going to accept this one.

Comment: Again, this answer does not provide an exact equivalent, since the Julia code copies while the Python code returns views.

Comment: @JiahaoChen doing `row1, row2 = a` is not copying anything AFAIKT: `julia> a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]; row1, row2 = a; row1[1] = 7; @assert a[1] == [7, 2]` vs `>>> a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]; row1, row2 = a; row1[0] = 7; assert a[0] == [7, 2]`, actually it's the same array/list (same id/object), i'd be more worried about performance, but sometimes one actually wants arrays of arrays instead of a matrix as a data structure, it all depends.

Comment: My mistake. I don't know why I said that anymore.

Answer (score 3):

The shortest one-liner I can think of in Julia is

```
r1, r2 = [sub(a, i, :) for i=1:2]
```

it's not as efficient as writing out

```
r1 = sub(a, 1, :)
r2 = sub(a, 2, :)
```

because the first version creates a temporary array and then unpacks it into the tuple on the left hand side.

### Note:

New versions of NumPy (1.10 or so) now returns views of arrays, not copies. In Julia 0.4, views are created by *sub*, and copies are created by slicing. So in Julia

```
r1 = a[1,:]
```

is *not* equivalent to the analogous NumPy/Python statement

```
r1 = a[0,:]
```

The main difference between views and copies is that changing the entries of a will change the entries of r1 if r1 is a view, but not if r1 is a copy. The disadvantage of copies is that they take up more memory.

Comment: Has `sub` been replaced by `view`?

Comment: `row1, row2 = view.(Ref(a), [1,2], :)`

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in Julia are a bit more general (they can be more than 2-d matrices). So the meaning of "rows" is less clear and there might be more options of slicing the array which the programmer intends. Therefore more info needs to be put into the expression.

The version I came up with is:

```
row1, row2 = ([vec(a[i,:]) for i in 1:size(a,1)]...)
```

Explanation:

- `([ ]...)` creates a tuple out of a vector
- `size(a,2)` returns the number of rows
- `vec( )` transforms an array into a vector, since the indexed matrix is a matrix.
- `[ <...> for i in <...>]` is an array comprehension (Python has them too)
- `row1, row2 = <...tuple...>` unpacks a tuple and assigns values to variables.

All the general languages like Julia and Python are Turing-complete, so everything can be done, but it is unnecessary to expect the code to be too similar. The Julia way is hopefully the better way.

Comment: Thanks. Very slightly more succinct, `row1, row2 = [a[i,:][:] for i in 1:size(a,1)]`

Comment: Although tbh I'm a bit surprised there doesn't seem to be an even easier to read version a la Python... I don't totally see a problem with the meaning though, Numpy has N-D arrays just the same and its clear what is meant when unpacking one into a tuple of variables.

Comment: Note that a[1,:] in Julia 0.4 is _not_ equivalent to a[0,:] in Python/NumPy, for newer versions of NumPy (v1.9+). The former returns a copy while the latter returns a view.

Answer (score 1):

julia 1.1 offers [`eachrow`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.eachrow)

```
a = [[1 2]; [3 4]]
row1, row2 = eachrow(a)

row1, row2                 # ([1, 2], [3, 4])
```

There is also [`eachcol`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.eachcol).